# How can I lay two canvas elements on top of each other?

Tags: html, css, canvas

I want to lay two canvas elements on top of each other. I have tried this, but they always appear one below the other.
Canvas with id canvas1 should be the lower plane and canvas2 the upper plane.

```html
<div class="container">
    <canvas class="canvas" id="canvas1" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    <canvas class="canvas" id="canvas2" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

#canvas1,
#canvas2{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a position property to `#canvas1`, and used the `z-index` property.  The higher the `z-index`, the higher it will be displayed.  All you need is for the `z-index` in whatever you want on top to be higher than the `z-index` of what you want below.

```css
#canvas1 {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  z-index: -1;
}
#canvas2{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <canvas class="canvas" id="canvas1" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    <canvas class="canvas" id="canvas2" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When i do this, there is the black canvas element (canvas1) at the top and the red canvas element (canvas2) at the bottom. But I want them to overlap.

Comment: @elli perhaps I'm misunderstanding something.  Do you want them to be slightly transparent so that you can see through the overlapping part?  If not, do you have an example image of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: The lower layer should be a shape, e.g. a rectangle. I want to upload an image to the upper layer. You should still see the rectangle despite the image. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: If the canvas elements are empty, it shows them in top of each other. But if an object is inside the canvas element, it shows the elements one below the other.